# Small signature for packets using asymetric encryption?

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves

The smallest signature sizes that I can find are for elliptic curve public key systems where the signature is 4 times the security level (2 x the key size). In my case I can change the key every day, after which it is OK if the key is revealed.

So my questions are:

1. is there a more efficient signature than 2 x key size?
2. what would be the minimal acceptable key size for implementations over the next 10 years or so. Looking at a table of key size vs. operations to crack I get a 108 bit ECC key requires 1.8 x 10^8 MIPS, but I'm not sure how to interpret MIPS these days when graphics processors are so powerful. Is 1.8 x 10^8 MIPS a lot of compute power?

Comment: Are you aware of symmetric [message authentication codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code), or do you absolutely need to sign every packet with a public key signature?  Because the obvious alternative would be to use symmetric crypto;  compute a MAC tag over each packet.  [SipHash](https://131002.net/siphash/) was designed with this sort of application in mind, and produces 64-bit tags.

Comment: I believe I need a public key signature because I cannot trust that someone who has the symmetric key will not be the guy who tries to spoof messages.

Comment: I don't know the exact details of your problem, but I'd say don't rule out a MAC-based solution too quickly. For example, if you need to prove to yourself that you were the author of a message, one simple approach is to use a MAC to tag your own messages with a key only you have.

Comment: In my case I have a device that is broadcasting interesting information that someone else may want to spoof, either by replay or by synthesizing wrong information, and my solution is to publish a public key and then sign each broadcast message using the corresponding private key. I cannot use a session key because there is no path to send a message from the listener to the broadcaster. I can update the keys periodically though, once a day would be easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Signature-Scheme known for it's short signatures is the [Boneh-Lynn-Shacham (BLS) Signature Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boneh%E2%80%93Lynn%E2%80%93Shacham), that uses not only Elliptic Curves but Bilinear Pairings over the curve.
The paper can be found [here](https://www.iacr.org/archive/asiacrypt2001/22480516.pdf) and lists signature sizes provided. For example the paper states that you can

> … get a signature of length 154 bits with security comparable to 320-bit DSA or 320-bit ECDSA …

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. Looks like signatures are half the ECDSA algorithm which is a big improvement.

Comment: Beware that there have been results that show that the BLS signature is not as secure as ECDSA for the same key sizes, see e.g. [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/76205/1172).